# Is there any way to use onmouseover and onmousedown together?

Tags: javascript, html, events

This code works fine for `onMouseOver` and `onMouseOut` events, but it doesn't work for `onMouseDown`.
Here is the code that I wrote in HTML5 and JavaScript. Let me know the mistakes that I am make. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
     <title>Zero cross</title>
 </head>

<body>
    <script>
        function changecolor(vals) {
            document.getElementById(vals).style.color = "red";
            document.getElementById(vals).innerHTML = "Click to select";
        }

        function changeagain(vals) {
            document.getElementById(vals).style.color = "#000000";
            if (vals == 'cross') {
                document.getElementById(vals).innerHTML = "X";
            } else {
                document.getElementById(vals).innerHTML = "0";
            }
        }

        function selection(vals) {
            document.getElementById(vals).style.color = "yellow";
            if (vals == 'cross') {
                document.getElementById(vals).innerHTML = "X";
            } else {
                document.getElementById(vals).innerHTML = "0";
            }
        }
    </script>

    <div align="center">
        <p id="cross" onmouseover="changecolor('cross');" onmouseout="changeagain('cross');" onmousedown="selection();">
            X
        </p>
        <p id="zero" onmouseover="changecolor('zero');" onmouseout="changeagain('zero');" onmousedown="selection();">
            0
        </p>

    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you forgot to send the Id

```
<p id="cross" onmouseover="changecolor('cross');" onmouseout="changeagain('cross');" onmousedown="selection('cross');">
            X
        </p>
        <p id="zero" onmouseover="changecolor('zero');" onmouseout="changeagain('zero');" onmousedown="selection('zero');">
            0
        </p>
```

Check `onmousedown="selection('zero');"` and `onmousedown="selection('cross');"`